# Getting a value using only the primary key and foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

I have already tried several `queries` and `joins` and I can't solve this question.

I have 2 tables

```
Employee
--------
ID(PK)                                                                                                                                     
Firstname                                                                                                                                                  
Lastname                                                                                                                                                  
ContactNumber                                                                                                                                                  
Position                                                                         
TeamleaderID(FK) //*which is only applicable if the position isn't a team leader*//

Team Leader
----------
ID(PK)                                                                         
employeeID(FK)
```

`Employee` table consists of 2 data, the first one is.

```
ID(PK) - 1                                                                         
Firstname - Mikael                                                                                                                               
Lastname - Roque                                                                                                                     
ContactNumber - 0010101                                                                                                             
Position - TeamLeader                                                                                                                                                                                              
TeamleaderID(FK) - Null
```

2nd one is

```
ID(PK) - 2                                                                         
Firstname - Rinnie                                                                         
Lastname - Hoshino                                                                         
ContactNumber - 0010101                                                                         
Position - Engineer                                                                         
TeamleaderID(FK) - 1
```

3rd one is for the `teamleader` table

```
ID(PK) - 1                                                                         
employeeID(FK) - 1
```

I've tried this query

```
SELECT employee.*                                                                         
FROM employee                                                                         
JOIN teamleader                                                                         
ON employee.teamleader_id=teamleader.teamleader_id                                                                         
Where employee.firstname='Rinnie';
```

but the result is the `teamleader` id was only shown. Is it possible to select all the `employee` data including the name of the `teamleader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the query as shown.  The issue with your posted query is that you are not selecting the team leader's name, only the original employee.  To get the team leader's name as well, you will have to join to another instance of the employee table (employee_1) and link to the employeeId field in table  teamleader.

```
SELECT e.*, m.FirstName as TeamLead
FROM employee e
join teamlead on e.TeamleaderId = teamlead.ID
join employee m on teamlead.employeeID = m.ID
WHERE e.FirstName = "Rinnie";
```

Cheers,

Comment: I removed the 2nd on statement and that did the trick... thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, I tried to remove the 2nd join and that's where an error came from wherein they only show the name of the team leader, maybe removing it is a big mistake, anyway I tried your query but said error on line 6... the second on statement.

Comment: Edited to follow MySQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need another join for getting result:

```
SELECT employee.*,leader.*
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN teamleader ON employee.teamleader_id=teamleader.teamleader_id
LEFT JOIN employee as leader ON teamleader.employeeID = leader.ID
Where employee.firstname='Rinnie';
```

I added left join for employeee without teamleader.